# Functional place to do rate limiting

Tags: python

Supposing that I have an API call that I want to employ rate-limiting on. Something like:

```
1 def rate_limited_function(request):
2 
3    if not request.POST.get('user_id'):
4        return BadResponse
5    else:
6
7        # do function
```

Where would the rate counter usually be implemented -- on line 2, at the start of the function, or on line 6? Why would it be better to implement one over the other?

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would suggest limiting the rate at which the function that generates the HTTP request is called. For example:

```
def run(something):
    if somecondition:
       sleep x
       rate_limited_function(user_id)

def rate_limited_function(user_id)
    #work happening here
```

The reason I would do it this way is because this way you could make the function performing the work multi threaded without causing threads to wait. Additionally any other higher level functions wont be waiting on the HTTP execution. Additionally it could be hard to track if you are using a counter doing it at the working level.

Comment: Thanks, what is the `sleep x` here for in the above example?

Comment: threw it in for context.. nothing particular but if you wanted to fire off the request and wait for x number of seconds before executing it you could do it in that manner. occasionally comes in hand.